# How to find the total memory allocated during a method call in java , including the memory garbage collected during the time of call?

Tags: java, memory

How to find the total memory allocated during a process (say a method call) in java , including the memory garbage collected during the time of process also?

Comment: You have to understand that memory usage in Java is not directly related and/or can be calculated (reliably). There are many methods to **estimate** memory usage at a given point, but they are not reliable and 100% correct

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you suggest some methods used to find the memory usage.

Comment: Look at the code in this - it will give you a starting point https://gist.github.com/GArlington/063b6d6395be3f72c2b4